# WPF, Drag and select elements (mouse)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-core-3.1

How to select elements using a rectangle drawn by the mouse in C # / wpf ?

i was searching how to select elements (in my case it was a listview) by drawing a rectangle selection around/go over elements, perhaps it's because it was late in the night, but examples i found was a bit hard to understand. Then after passed some hours to try a lot of things examinate sources i found, i made a little project just to help people with a very basic example.

Answer (score 0):

It's really perfectible, selection can be drawn beyond limits but i wanted to make something really basic, a first step. I let a lot of comments to help to understand. I tried to split design part and code part the most possible, i let Name for shapes to help to differentiate for the debugging, there is also a name for the selection box. I hope it will useful.

- Wpf Part: it's made with a border to show limits, the part where you can select elements has a margin to show that is important to specify a container reacting to the mouse. If you want to just select a part in your Page/Window, it's important to keep in mind that there is relative position to get. If not you will draw your rectangle with a gap.

Shapes will have their stroke thickness modified to help to see how it works. You can change the geometry to see how it reacts.

```
<Window x:Class="FirstSelect.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FirstSelect"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>

        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="50" >
            <Grid  
                  MouseLeftButtonDown="Grid_MouseLeftButtonDown"
                    MouseLeftButtonUp="Grid_MouseLeftButtonUp"
                    MouseMove="Grid_MouseMove" 
                >
                <!-- Used for the overlay  -->
                <Canvas >
                    <Rectangle Fill="AliceBlue"  x:Name="SelectBox" Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="2" RadiusX="5"/>
                </Canvas>
                <!-- Container, set background to transparent is important to see the overlay -->
                <Grid x:Name="Container" Background="Transparent" >

                    <Rectangle x:Name="vert" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="129" Margin="154,136,0,0" Stroke="Green" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="110"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="rose" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="161" Margin="519,71,0,0" Stroke="pink" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>

                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

- Code Part:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace FirstSelect
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Keep the initial position when you clicked
        /// </summary>
        Point _InitPos;

        /// <summary>
        /// A Flag to filter and active selection only when mouse button is held
        /// </summary>
        bool _LeftMouseHeld = false;

        /// <summary>
        /// Collection of elements selected
        /// </summary>
        private List<object> _ResultsList = new List<object>();

        private void Grid_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            var Limit = (FrameworkElement)sender;
            foreach (Rectangle rectangle in _ResultsList)
            {
                rectangle.StrokeThickness = 1;
            }
            _ResultsList.Clear();

            // Get position relative to the grid content
            _InitPos = e.GetPosition(Limit);

            // With this, selection is more fluid but you can draw beyond limit of your container
            Limit.CaptureMouse();

            // Initialization of the SelectBox
            Canvas.SetLeft(SelectBox, _InitPos.X);
            Canvas.SetTop(SelectBox, _InitPos.X);
            SelectBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

            // Set left mouse button state because mosemove will continue to draw if not filtered
            _LeftMouseHeld = true;

            Debug.WriteLine($"{_InitPos.X}, {_InitPos.Y}");
        }


        private void Grid_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            var Limit = (FrameworkElement)sender;

            // Set left mouse button state to released
            _LeftMouseHeld = false;

            Limit.ReleaseMouseCapture();

            // Hide all the listbox (if you forget to specify width and height you will have remanent coordinates
            SelectBox.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            SelectBox.Width = 0;
            SelectBox.Height = 0;

            if (_ResultsList.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (FrameworkElement r in _ResultsList)
                    Debug.WriteLine(r.Name);
            }
        }


        private void Grid_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Grid Limit = (Grid)sender;

            // to calculate only if left mouse button is held;
            if (_LeftMouseHeld)
            {
                // Get current position relative to the grid content
                Point currentPos = e.GetPosition(Limit);

                /*
                    Parameters can't be negative then we will invert base according to mouse value
                */

                // X coordinates
                if (currentPos.X > _InitPos.X)
                {
                    Canvas.SetLeft(SelectBox, _InitPos.X);
                    SelectBox.Width = currentPos.X - _InitPos.X;
                }
                else
                {
                    Canvas.SetLeft(SelectBox, currentPos.X);
                    SelectBox.Width = _InitPos.X - currentPos.X;
                }

                // Y coordinates
                if (currentPos.Y > _InitPos.Y)
                {
                    Canvas.SetTop(SelectBox, _InitPos.Y);
                    SelectBox.Height = currentPos.Y - _InitPos.Y;
                }
                else
                {
                    Canvas.SetTop(SelectBox, currentPos.Y);
                    SelectBox.Height = _InitPos.Y - currentPos.Y;
                }

                /*
                 * With a rectangle geometry you could add every shapes INSIDE the rectangle
                 * With a point geometry you must go over the shape to select it.
                 */
                VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(Container,
                    new HitTestFilterCallback(Filter),
                    new HitTestResultCallback(MyHitTestResult),
                    /*new PointHitTestParameters(currentPos)*/
                    new GeometryHitTestParameters(new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(_InitPos, currentPos)))
                    );
            }
        }

        
        private HitTestFilterBehavior Filter(DependencyObject potentialHitTestTarget)
        {
            // Type of return is very important
            if (potentialHitTestTarget is Rectangle)
            {
                if (!_ResultsList.Contains(potentialHitTestTarget))
                {

                    _ResultsList.Add(potentialHitTestTarget);
                    ((Rectangle)potentialHitTestTarget).StrokeThickness = 5;
                }
                return HitTestFilterBehavior.ContinueSkipChildren;
            }
            
            return HitTestFilterBehavior.Continue;

        }


        // Return the result of the hit test to the callback.
        public HitTestResultBehavior MyHitTestResult(HitTestResult result)
        {
            // Set the behavior to return visuals at all z-order levels.
            return HitTestResultBehavior.Continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Best regards, Vonkel/Daerlnaxe